# An attempt to a triple integral with spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> If $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ and $D=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x\geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0,\; x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$, find $$
> \iiint_D f(x,y,z).
> $$

I tried to solve this with spherical coordinates: $x=\rho\sin\psi\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\psi\sin\theta, z=\rho\cos\psi$.

Since $\rho>0$ the condition $z\geq 0$ implies $\rho\cos\psi\geq0$ therefore $0\leq\psi\leq \pi/2$. Considering $y\geq0$ I have that $\rho\sin\psi\sin\theta\geq0$, with the former condition for $\psi$ I have $\sin\psi\geq0$ then I need $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$; but $x\geq0$ implies also must be $\rho\sin\psi\cos\theta\geq0$ then $0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

And $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1$ implies that $\rho^2\sin^2\psi\cos^2\theta+\rho\sin^2\psi\sin^2\theta+\rho^2\cos^2\psi=\rho^2$.

Then the conditions are as follows:
$$0\leq\rho\leq1 \\0\leq\psi\leq\pi/2\\0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$$

The Jacobian for spherical coordinates is given by $\rho^2\sin\psi$, then the integral is given by

$$
\begin{align}
\iiint_D f(x,y,z) &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 r^5 \sin^2\psi \cos\psi \sin\theta \cos\theta\;dr d\psi d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{6} \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta \cos\theta \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\psi \cos\psi\; d\psi d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{18} \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta \cos\theta\; d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{18}\sin^2\theta|_0^{\pi/2} \\
&= \frac{1}{18}.
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I have not worked the problem out,  but your limits of integration are correct.

Comment: @Dante: Yes it is correct. Congratulations! :)